# Rephrasing the proposition that $a$ is an accumulation point of $S$ iff $\exists (a_n) \in S$ with the limit as $a$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

In the book of *Real Analysis* of T. Terzioğlu at page 24, it is given that

[image]
[image]

I as far as I understand the condition for $a_n \not = a_m$ for $n \not = m$ is we want a sequence which is not a constant sequence at the point $a$.

**So my question is that can we rephrase this proposition as 
... there exists a sequence $(a_n) \in S$ with $\lim a_n =a$ provided that $\exists n_1$ such that $a_{n_1} \not = a$.**

Comment: What do you understand by an accumulation point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot rephrase it like that.

Simply demanding *one* value $n_1$ for which $a_{n_1}\neq a$ can still lead to a sequence like
$$b,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,\dots$$

for which the limit is $a$, even though $a$ is not an accumulation point. What you instead have to say is

> There exists a sequence $(a_n)\in S$ with $\lim a_n=a$ such that for every $N$, there exists some $n>N$ such that $a_n\neq a$.